# Is there any kind of file dependency tracer for Asp.Net apps?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have an Asp.Net 2.0 (VB.Net) app and I'm trying to export a Control (ASCX) to another project. I need to know what other files that the Control needs in order to work.

Is there any way - using VS.Net 2005 or an external app - to recursively trace the dependencies of a page or control in a solution?

For example, for this file: `~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx`, I'd like to get the following list of files that it depends on to run:

```
~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx
  ~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx.vb
    ~/App_Code/SomeClass.vb
      ~/App_Code/AnotherClass.vb
      ~/App_WebReferences/com/example/SomeWebService/SomeWebService.disco
      ~/App_WebReferences/com/example/SomeWebService/SomeWebService.discomap
      ~/App_WebReferences/com/example/SomeWebService/SomeWebService.wsdl
    ~/App_Code/AnotherClass.vb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229864(VS.80).aspx) or maybe ProcMon...

One of my coworkers suggested this app called Dependency Auditor. I haven't used it though and am not vouching for it necessarily.

Comment: Hmm, that addin appears to be for Excel, not VS 2005.

Comment: Fuze is built for this, hard to start with but amazingly useful.

Comment: hmm, my googling skills can't seem to find fuze/fuse log viewer for vs.net can you provide a link?

Comment: I don't think you need to dl it if you are running visual studio. You can access it via the VS Command Window. here is a helpful link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(vs.71).aspx

Comment: oh wow, that's really handy, unfortunately it only shows failures or all assembly binding, it doesn''t show assemblies or files for specific project items

Comment: yeah that's true. Sorry about that. It's the best I could come up with.

Comment: The MSDN docs for fuslogvw.exe indicate the need to click the ASP.NET option.  Unfortunately the version I have on WindowsXP does not have the ASP.NET option.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [AutomatedQA's AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) do this kind of thing.  You can view sequence diagrams, call graphs, etc....  From there you can see which assemblies and files are being used.

They have a free trial that will give you plenty of time to do what you need to do.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, but seems like a bit overkill for what I'm looking for. I just want to select some files in a project and get the other files in the project that they depend on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MZ Tools 6.0 integrates with Visual Studio and has a "get callers" type feature.
http://www.mztools.com/v6/mztools6.aspx

Comment: Interesting, that Procedure Callers function is pretty sweet. I'm looking for a tool that can just generate a list of files based on other files though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)? There's a [plugin for Reflector](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Graph) as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks Andy! Long time no see :-) Those are both cool but a bit overkill for what I'm looking for. While those give great stats for projects, I'm looking for something where I can pick out a few files in a project. At this point I think I may just have to build it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There's no way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to continue doing it by hand. Or write a solution myself...

Answer (score -1):

I would just move the ascx control to a new project and debug stuff one by one.   Then, I would compile that into a dll and use it in the different project.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. :-)